# How to kill/signal other child processes from another child process?

Tags: c++, c, process, kill

I am having a bit of trouble figuring out exactly how the `kill(pid_t pid, int sig)` function works when using it in a child process. In my program, I have the parent, and 8 child processes created with `fork()`. I've been searching and reading online to no avail unfortunately. All of the searched yield results about killing children from the parent process.

I have signal handlers set up in each process, except they are not working correctly.

Basically, I need to signal all of the processes in the process group from the child process "signal_generating_process", but for some reason the signals are not going through correctly.

On the man page, kill(2) says that if I use 0 as the first argument, it will send the signal to all processes in the process group, but its not working correctly for me. I'll include the code for the signal generator as well as one of the signal handlers. Feel free to ask for more information if I haven't included enough. Thank you all very much!

```
void signal_generating_process(){
    signal(SIGINT, end_process_handler);
    block_sigusr1();
    block_sigusr2();
    while(true){
        millisleep(randomFloat(.01,.1)); //function I created to sleep for a certain amount of milliseconds
        int sig = rand_signal(); //randomly picks between sigusr1 and sigusr2
        kill(0, sig);
        if(sig == SIGUSR1){ //adds to a counter for sigusr1
            pthread_mutex_lock(&shm_ptr->mutex1_sent);
            shm_ptr->SIGUSR1_sent++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&shm_ptr->mutex1_sent);
        }
        else{ //signal == SIGUSR2 - adds to a counter for sigusr2
            pthread_mutex_lock(&shm_ptr->mutex2_sent);
            shm_ptr->SIGUSR2_sent++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&shm_ptr->mutex2_sent);
        }
    }
}
```

Process that handles sigusr1 and the signal handler (sigusr2 is the same):

```
void sigusr1_receiving_process(){
    block_sigusr2();
    signal(SIGUSR1, sigusr1_handler);
    signal(SIGINT, end_process_handler);
    while(true){
        sleep(1);
    }
}
void sigusr1_handler(int signal){
    printf("Signal 1 Received\n");
    if(signal == SIGUSR1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&shm_ptr->mutex1_received);
        shm_ptr->SIGUSR1_received++;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&shm_ptr->mutex1_received);
    }
}
```

When these loops go through, "Signal 1 Received" is never printed throughout the course of the entire execution. Is there anything that you can tell is obviously wrong with how I'm handling signals?

Edit: I fixed my problem! Unfortunately, it had nothing to do with what I have above, so I apologize for people who find this question in the future looking for an answer.

Anyway, if you do stumble upon it, maybe it has to do with the way you block signals. I blocked signals incorrectly in the parent process, so they transferred over into the child processes.  If you're having this issue, maybe check how you have blocked signals.

Comment: regarding the expression: `randomFloat(.01,.1));`  It would seem that the function: `randomFloat()` would be expecting `float` parameters, but those parameters are `double`.  Suggest: `randomFloat(.01f,.1f));`

Comment: There are many functions that are not to be used in a signal handler.  Amongst those functions is: `printf()`  However, `write( 1, ... , ... )`  is ok.  Further info can be found via: `man 7 signal` and `man 7 signal-safety`

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that you had to put 'f' after a float to specify that it is a float, because it did end up outputting a correct value, I'll remember that for the future.

The printf was also only used for a test to make sure the signal was actually received, so I ended up removing it when I got the signals to work correctly, but I will remember that for the future as well, thank you!

Comment: [mcve] would help.